# Cant access SSIS packages in MSDB folder via SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

> The SQL Server instance specified in SSIS service configuration is not
>   present or is not available. This might occur when there is no default
>   instance of SQL Server on the computer. For more information, see the
>   topic "Configuring the Integration Services Service" in Server 2008
>   Books Online.
>
> Login failed for user 'XXXXX'. (MsDtsSrvr)

After connecting to Intergation Services on the server, I get the above error error message when i try open the MSDB folder under Stored Packages. This is a default instance of SQl server. I've checked the MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml file and all looks fine. The user has access to MSDB system tables. Can anyone recommend any thing else to check?

Comment: Try to use the profiler and capture errors - it should give you an idea about which object is needed and which one is possibly missing. The other hint might be to ensure that all the latest updates are applied.

Comment: I would think that the login failed portion of the message is the more important piece.  The objects may very well be there, but not visible to you as a user since the login failed.

Comment: I know but the user has permission to the msdb table. The user is an admin on the server

Comment: I had to add the user as a login to the SQL server with sys_admin rights to msdb

Comment: @davey – add your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add the user as a login to the SQL server with sys_admin rights to msdb (taken from last comment in reply to the original question, by davey, @june 19th at 21:54which worked for me - this is the answer)